# Is cryptography an interesting field for research?

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography

I am now styding for first year bachelor's degree in Mathematics for IT. In the future I would like to major in the same field and possibly continue trying to get a Ph.D. But I still have options to take a different path.

Even though I have a long journey ahead, I am thinking about trying to write a "scientific bachelor's thesis" (that's how we call bachelor's thesis with scientific results on my university in my language) when the time comes.

Is cryptography a field with interesting and imporant problems to solve? I know about some interesting problems like P=NP and some stuff about (post-)quantum cryptography, but surely that's not what majority of problems are like.

So, is cryptography a field where it is easy to find meaningful and interesting problems to solve?

*(I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this, so please inform me if I should ask somewhere else.)*

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not an on-topic question. Nevertheless, here's an answer of sorts: yes, cryptography is an interesting field, and yes, many problems are open. The P ?= NP problem is a (fundamental) theoretical computer science problem, not really a cryptography problem. You may think that the interesting problems are all in areas such as post-quantum cryptography, but I'd like to argue in this comment that "good old" symmetric-key cryptography also provides mathematically interesting problems. Any block cipher, hash function... provides an (in my opinion) interesting problem: break it.

Comment: There are meaningful problems to be found in countless fields of study, including this one. Whether it is an interesting field is a question only you can answer.

Answer (score 4):

Cryptography is a nice field in which not only problems to solve are a-plenty, but it is also one of these fields where individuals can make significant discoveries in a relatively short time. A PhD student in cryptography will typically write three or four articles during his thesis; by comparison, a "pure mathematics" PhD student will generally produce a single article in the same time. Informally, to make new advances, you have to first learn the existing science; in cryptography, this means getting up to date with about 40 years of research. In mathematics, that's closer to 200 years, hence the comparatively higher effort to reach the "publishable" state.

Moreover, cryptography is an applied field, by which I mean that it has immediate practical applications. This means money: you can make a very nice living out of cryptographic expertise. A PhD is a very good key to unlock such things (I have a PhD and I am a consultant in cryptography, and my experience is that both facts are related). Intellectual fulfilment is of primordial importance to a balanced life, and money does not make happiness; but money is still some super useful stuff, and being able to live out of doing intellectually rewarding things is a nice combination to achieve.

In any case, mathematics are always useful for anything related to computers. A lot of computer users and developers can get along with a very low understanding of the underlying principles, but the maths are what *explains* why computers work that way. Mathematics allow to look beyond the magic.

Answer (score 0):

I studied math in college, but now am a Ph.D. student in Cryptography. So maybe I can share my thoughts.

In my opinion, Cryptography is a research area neither as theoretical as math nor as practical as information security. But Cryptography plays a role to connect them somehow. So math background can be helpful, but cryptography has its own "language". Crypto seems to cover everything related to security that can be formally proved. But here proofs in Crypto often mean ''reductions'' (similar to those in Complexity) and depend on some underlying assumptions such as the well-known big integer factorization problem. So it is not the same kind of proof as math does. Crypto research also covers building cryptographic schemes or attacking them (a.k.a., cryptoanalysis). So here is a big picture of Crypto research:

1) I think most crypto researchers are trying to construct "good" schemes and prove that they achieve some security goals based on well-established assumptions. As you mentioned, some post-quantum crypto area like lattice-based crypto does involve some math especially algebra knowledge. But of course, math is used in other crypto areas too. I think different crypto areas are basically depending on different underlying assumptions :) For instance, you can check functional encryption for some interesting assumptions.

2) Some crypto researchers are trying to attack the crypto schemes. A couple of years ago, Wang attacked several prevalent hash functions (which is used as building blocks of many crypto schemes). For this kind of area, math student may need to learn some implementation stuff.

3) Some crypto researchers are trying to analyze some protocols (or applications) implemented by security people in a cryptographic way. Maybe this is contra-intuitive, but frequently people use some security schemes without knowing if it is provably secure or not! What's worse, even for provably secure schemes, they can be implemented in the wrong way. Maybe you have heard about the Heartbleed bug.

I think Crypto does contain a lot of interesting topics. But you definitely need to learn some Crypto "language" before doing a project. I think Prof. Boneh's Applied Crypto course (available online at Coursera) is a good resource to start.

Answer (score -5):

Drop the maths.  There is no maths in IT and no useful maths at all in general unless you do investment banking.  Despite what teachers tell you (they're lying) qualifications are not required in IT, only experience and ability. Absolutely do not do a PhD (makes you unemployable) unless you intend to work in Germany.   You can easily prove the truth of what I say by spending some time on the main site (stackoverflow /jobs).  Learn Java + Javascript and get experience.  If you can't get experience but know what you're doing, just lie on your CV.  That's how winners get ahead.

As to cryptography, it's likely that it will stagnate /die out as quantum key distribution matures.  As soon as it's exchange rate is improved to the point of transmitting raw data rather than only keys, only one time pads will be required.  Even children can use a one time pad.  And it's resistant to quantum computation.  At that point, encryption will become the domain of physicists and engineers.  It's understandable to want to protect your rice bowl, but remember that the Luddites and coal miners were swept away.  I generalise (somewhat) but I hope that you get the idea.

I guess that it might remain for disc encryption /ATM cards, or other scenarios where fibre optics aren't natively used.  But there'll be nothing remaining to get a decent high salary over.  Overly pessimistic?  Daft?  Ask a black or yellow cab driver.  Just sayin'.

Comment: I would *strongly* disagree that Quantum Key Distribution would necessarily displace all of crypto.  Even if it becomes economically competitive to do fiber optic encryption (and I'm not holding my breath), there are a *lot* of other places crypto is used where QKD isn't applicable; you listed a couple (which aren't as trivial as you make out), there are others (IOT, protection of RF communication (Wifi/Cellphone), evoting, ecurrency (bitcoin and friends), to name a few examples...)

Comment: And, while I'm disagreeing, I would also disagree with the notion that 'there [are] ... no useful maths at all in general unless you do investment banking" [why investment banking in particular?]; there are lots of fields that use advanced math, and cryptography is just one of them.  It's not clear if punga would be interested in those fields, they most certain do exist...

Comment: I think the original poster was asking about intellectual fulfillment, not about vocational employability.  And there's no mathematics in IT only if you consciously choose to ignore it—even if you inexplicably exclude cryptography from IT on the nonsensical premise that one day it will one day be supplanted by a special-purpose wholesale replacement of the internet to do what the computer in your pocket can do at a thousand times the speed for a millionth the price.

Comment: "Mathematics for IT" is name of my study program. It basically branches into cryptography and computer graphics.